# What is a correct step by step logic of exporting scene with baked occlusion for loading it at runtime?

Tags: 3d, unity, scene

I wonder what is a correct step by step logic of exporting scene with baked occlusion (Culling data) for loading that scene at runtime (on fly from the internet for example))?

So currently my plan looks like this:

- I create prefabs
- Place them onto my scene (into Hierarchy) (say create 20 buffolows and some hourses and some buildings)
- Create empty prefab and drag all my scene objects from hierarchy onto it
- Export prefab

So generally I put all my scene objects into one large prefab and export it but it seems that all objects that were marked as static get this property turned off when loading them at runtime and so no Frustum Culling, and no Occlusion culling happens.

So I wonder what is a correct way of exporting Scene + Objects + Occlusion (and other culing) data for future load of such scene at runtime?

I wonder about current `3.5.2 Pro` and future `4 Pro` versions of U3D.

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole point of Static is that it only applies to objects that are placed in the scene and stay there throughout - not ones you load via `Resources.Load()`, for example.